# WebSocket connection to 'wss://learning-backend.thinksys.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, strapi

I am building a video proctoring web application using VueJS, Strapi and socket.io . But i am getting the error that websocket connection has failed. This is the error which i am getting in the console "WebSocket connection to 'wss://myWebsiteUrl.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:".
P.S - I don't want to establish polling transport connection.

This is my Client side code

```
import { reactive } from "vue";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const state = reactive({
  connected: false,
  // fooEvents: [],
  // barEvents: [],
});

// "undefined" means the URL will be computed from the `window.location` object
const URL = process.env.VUE_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE;

export const socket = io(URL, {
  autoConnect: false,
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.VUE_APP_MY_FRONTED_URL,
    credentials: true
  },
  transports: ["websocket"],
});

socket.on("connect", () => {
  state.connected = true;
  console.log("socket connected");
});

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  state.connected = false;
  console.log("socket disconnected!!!");
});

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});
```

This is my Server Side Strapi configuration in plugin.js

```
"io": {
      enabled: true,
      config: {
        IOServerOptions: {
          cors: { origin: env("FRONTEND_URL","https://myWebsiteUrl.com"), methods: ["GET", "POST"] },
          pingTimeout: 30000, // wait 30 seconds for a response from the client
          pingInterval: 1000, // send a ping message every 1 second to check client connection status
        },
        contentTypes: {
          // post: "*",
          // blog:["create", "find", "publish"]
        },
        events: [
          {
            name: "connection",
            handler: ({ strapi }, socket) => {
              strapi.log.info(`[io] new connection with id ${socket.id}`);

              socketHandler({ strapi }, socket);
            },
          },
          // {
          //   name: "connection"
          // }
        ]
      },
    },
```

and this is my socket.js file on strapi server in config folder

```
const { uploadRecoding } = require('../src/utils/uploadRecording/uploadRecording')

exports.socketHandler = ({ strapi }, socket) => {
  // console.log(socket);
  let streamArray = [];
  let streamInfo = {};
  let startTime = null;

  const stopStream = async () => {
    if(!startTime)
      return;
      
    await uploadRecoding({ strapi }, socket, streamArray, startTime, streamInfo);

    streamArray = [];
    streamInfo = {};
    startTime = null;
  }

  socket.on('disconnect', async () => {
    console.log(`[io] disconnected with id ${socket.id}`);

    if (streamArray.length) {
      await stopStream();
    }
  });
  socket.on('reconnect', (attemptNumber) => {
    console.log(`Client reconnected after ${attemptNumber} attempts`);
  });

  socket.on('test-recording', async (params = {}) => {
    if (params.info) {
      streamInfo = params.info
      startTime = new Date();
    }

    else if (streamInfo.testId && params.data) {
      streamArray.push(params.data);
    }

    else if (params.stop && streamArray.length) {
      await stopStream();
    }
  });
}
```